# How to disable AWS RDS encryption?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I made AWS RDS using **db.t2.small** by mistake
[image]

I modified my RDS to **db.t2.micro** but it didn't work because of Encryption is enable in Configuration.

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know how to disable DB encryption to downgrade it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do something like exporting old data from encrypted instance to new one.

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html

> DB instances that are encrypted can't be modified to disable encryption.